# UPDATE all rows in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, sql-update

I'm trying to wrap my brain around what I'm doing wrong here.  This is the function that is called when I want to delete a record.  The record is deleted, but I want the display_order to reestablish itself, if the record that is delete is somewhere in the middle of the rows.  So that the first record will always be 1, the second always 2, etc.

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    require ("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id ='".$id."'");
    if ($delete){

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $reord = "UPDATE pages SET display_order = '".$counter."'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($reord) or die(mysqli_error());
            $counter++;
        }

        header("Location: admin.php");
    }else{
        echo "NOTHING DELETED id=".$id;
    }
?>
```

The error that I'm receiving is that all the records "display_order" are now updated to the maximum number of records, say for instance, I had four records, I deleted one of them, now all remaining records have a display_order of 3.

Comment: First $id = (int) $_GET['id']; to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: If I load `yourPage.php?id=%27%20OR%20%271%27%3D%271` it will delete every row in the `pages` table. http://bobby-tables.com/, [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add the page id as a WHERE condition to the query. Like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $reord = "UPDATE pages SET display_order = '".$counter."' WHERE page_id = '" . $row->page_id . "'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($reord) or die(mysqli_error());
    $counter++;
}
```

Note: If missing the WHERE clause all records in the `pages` table will be updated.

Comment: I added the WHERE clause, but now instead of ALL the records being set to the max number, I'm getting nothing.  All display_order values are staying the same.  Also, the syntax of your suggested code flagged an error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in delete.php on line 12.  I changed it from $row['page_id'] to $row->page_id

Comment: I don't know your current mysql table layout. Replace `page_id` by your id column's name. Also I didn't know your fetch mode. It seem to be FETCH_OBJ (after reading your error message). Use `$row->PROPERTY_NAME` instead of `$row['PROPERTY_NAME']`.. I have updated the answer